# What are the advantages/disadvantages of Generic List (Of Type) and Collections

Tags: .net

As the questions says I have always believed that a strongly typed list is a better appraoch that using collections. However after discussions with a colleague today I was wanting to have a better answer than "because I like them" Can anyone explain a) the major differences and the benefits/disadvantages of each approach.

Edit: Similar to [What advantage do you get with a collection over List(Of T) in .NET 2.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495591/what-advantage-do-you-get-with-a-collection-over-listof-t-in-net-2-0/495626#495626)

Comment: Is this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495591/what-advantage-do-you-get-with-a-collection-over-listof-t-in-net-2-0/495626#495626 ???

Comment: Smells like a dupe to me. Certainly covers a lot of the same territory.

Comment: I think this question is slightly broader - perhaps should be allowed to remain open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strongly-typed collections, including lists, based on generics allow you to program without having to check the types of the objects that you retrieve form the list.  It makes the code cleaner because you don't have to cast the object to use it and you don't have to worry about enumerators throwing casting exceptions due to the collection containing an object of the wrong type.  Granted you can get a lot of this through unit testing as well, but using generics lets the compiler do the checking at compile time rather than you having to do the checking at runtime.  This is much more efficient.  You can still mess things up by casting things inappropriately to get around the compile-time errors, but then you get what you deserve if you do this without appropriate checks.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to tvanfosson's reply that the generic collections will be considerably more efficient when you're storing value types.  For example, a List will occupy less memory and provide much faster access than an ArrayList that you put integers in.

If you absolutely must store objects of multiple types in a collection, you can always use List and do the casting as you would have with ArrayList.

I can't think of any reason other than backwards compatibility to use the old-style (i.e. non generic) collections in favor of the generic collections.